# How to add image extension dynamically?

Tags: php

MY problem is how to add the image extension dynamically.So that when the 
    user updates its profile it can show all the image types like jpg png or 
    jpeg.I know i have use png but dont know how to add dynamically 
    extension.And also please tell me how can i make the photos unique so that 
    if the user uploads his next profile image it may not get overwritten with 
    the old one.

```
   <img src="uploads/profile/profile'.$_SESSION['iduser'].'.png" class="img-
    responsive "img-circle"  alt="User Image" >  


   $files = $_FILES['uploadphoto'];
   $fileName = $_FILES['uploadphoto']['name'];
   $fileTmpName= $_FILES['uploadphoto']['tmp_name'];
   $fileSize =$_FILES['uploadphoto']['size'];
   $fileError =$_FILES['uploadphoto']['error'];
   $fileType =$_FILES['uploadphoto']['type'];
   $fileExt = explode('.',$fileName);
   $fileActualExt =strtolower(end($fileExt));
   if($fileType ='jpg' && $fileType ='png' && $fileType ='jpeg'){
   if($fileError === 0){
   if($fileSize < 5000000){
   $fileNewName = "profile".$id.".".$fileActualExt;
   $fileDestination ="uploads/profile/".$fileNewName;
   move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName,$fileDestination);
   $sqlImg = "UPDATE profilestatus SET status =0 WHERE iduser = '$id'";
   mysqli_query($conn,$sqlImg);
   }else{
        echo "Your file is to big to upload!";
        }
   }else{
        echo "There is an error!";
        }
  }
   else{
       echo "Photo cannot be uploaded! image is not of the type jpg png or 
       jpeg";
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function

```
if([name of the added file] > NULL){you change the name}else{you save the file on the server}
```

Comment: `$new_file_name = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(2));     if( $fileName > NULL ){$fileName = $new_file_name;}`